# Regular expression between two integers

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that will match the word `mark` to an integer greater or equal to 140000 and less than or equal to 150000.

So, for example, the minimum value would be `mark_140000` and the maximum value would be `mark_150000`.  The values `mark_139999` and `mark_150001` would be invalid.

I have a method that will match from 140000 to 149999:

```
"^mark_14[0-9]{4}$"
```

How can I get the maximum to include 150000?

Answer (score 6):

simple enough, just create 2 cases:

```
"^mark_(14[0-9]{4}|150000)$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex needs to account for all the possibilities of `140000` to `150000`

`^mark_1(4\d{4})|(50{4})`

Comment: The pipe isn't needed inside the character list; it acts as a character, not as an OR operator.

Comment: It's the same thing >.> test it on regex101 or equivalent

Comment: i am dense, youre right :)  `^(mark_1(?:4\d{4})|(?:50{4}))$` would get cleaner groups

Comment: Looks cleaner but doesn't bench the same `Regex1:   150000
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   10
Elapsed Time:    0.75 s,   752.54 ms,   752538 µs


Regex2:   150{4}
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   10
Elapsed Time:    0.83 s,   832.02 ms,   832025 µs`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small function that checks if the number part is in the range:

```
import re

data = """So for example the minimum value would be mark_140000 and the maximum value would be mark_150000. The values mark_139999 and mark_150001 would be     Many thanks and mark_100000000000000"""

rx = re.compile(r'mark_(\d+)')

def check(number):
    number = float(number)
    if 140000 <= number <= 150000:
        return True
    return False

matches = [match.group(0)
        for match in rx.finditer(data)
        if check(match.group(1))]
print(matches)
```

This yields

```
['mark_140000', 'mark_150000']
```